# Trouble with CSRF token validation in python django

Tags: django, django-templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2AOE.png)I'm currently working on a travel management using python django and I'm having issues with CSRF token validation. I've implemented CSRF protection in my application, but for some reason, it's not working as expected.if login with a user csrf issue were risen what is the reason for this but i give the csrf verification for the login page then what is the reason may occur this

Answer (score 0):

include   `{% csrf_token %}` inside your login form like below.

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```